# Filter the Array of objects based on another Array Object as condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects

```
const data = [
    { id: 0, ALT_VALUE: 11, DLT_VALUE: 76 },
    { id: 1, ALT_VALUE: 80, DLT_VALUE: 48 },
    { id: 2, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
    { id: 3, ALT_VALUE: 12, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
    { id: 4, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
    { id: 5, ALT_VALUE: 13, DLT_VALUE: 49 },
    { id: 6, ALT_VALUE: 76, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
    { id: 7, ALT_VALUE: 9, DLT_VALUE: 15 },
];
```

and I would like to filter it dynamically based on this array of objects

```
const filters = [
    { parameter: "ALT_VALUE", min: 8, max: 100 },
    { parameter: "DLT_VALUE", min: 30, max: 50 },
];
```

based on the filters, the final result supposed to be

```
[
  { id: 5, ALT_VALUE: 13, DLT_VALUE: 49 },
  { id: 1, ALT_VALUE: 80, DLT_VALUE: 48 },
]
```

I tried with this

```
const result = data.filter((el) => {
    return filters.filter((f) => {
        if (el[f.parameter] > f.min && el[f.parameter] < f.max) {
            return el;
        }
    });
});
```

But I get all of the data

```
[
  { id: 0, ALT_VALUE: 11, DLT_VALUE: 76 },
  { id: 1, ALT_VALUE: 80, DLT_VALUE: 48 },
  { id: 2, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
  { id: 3, ALT_VALUE: 12, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
  { id: 4, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
  { id: 5, ALT_VALUE: 13, DLT_VALUE: 49 },
  { id: 6, ALT_VALUE: 76, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
  { id: 7, ALT_VALUE: 9, DLT_VALUE: 15 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, `filters.filter()` returns an `Array`, which JavaScript sees as a truthy value. This means that every item in `data` passes your filter (each iteration yields an array, empty or not, which is interpreted as `true`), and everything is included.

By having your `filter` return a Boolean value instead, you can avoid JavaScript coercing an Array to a Boolean value:

```
const result = data.filter((el) => {
    // every will only return true if all filters match,
    // else it will return false
    return filters.every((f) => {
        if (el[f.parameter] > f.min && el[f.parameter] < f.max) {
            return el;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want all the filters to be respected you need to use every instead of filter.

If you use filter if any of filter rule is match it will result in adding that to final output.

```js
const data = [
    { id: 0, ALT_VALUE: 11, DLT_VALUE: 76 },
    { id: 1, ALT_VALUE: 80, DLT_VALUE: 48 },
    { id: 2, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
    { id: 3, ALT_VALUE: 12, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
    { id: 4, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
    { id: 5, ALT_VALUE: 13, DLT_VALUE: 49 },
    { id: 6, ALT_VALUE: 76, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
    { id: 7, ALT_VALUE: 9, DLT_VALUE: 15 },
];

const filters = [
    { parameter: "ALT_VALUE", min: 8, max: 100 },
    { parameter: "DLT_VALUE", min: 30, max: 50 },
];

const result = data.filter((el) => {
  return filters.every((f) => {
    if (el[f.parameter] > f.min && el[f.parameter] < f.max) {
      return el;
    }
  });
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `every` instead of second `filter`

`Array.prototype.every` will return true if every element in the array matches your condition in the callback

```js
const data = [
    { id: 0, ALT_VALUE: 11, DLT_VALUE: 76 },
    { id: 1, ALT_VALUE: 80, DLT_VALUE: 48 },
    { id: 2, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
    { id: 3, ALT_VALUE: 12, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
    { id: 4, ALT_VALUE: 90, DLT_VALUE: 100 },
    { id: 5, ALT_VALUE: 13, DLT_VALUE: 49 },
    { id: 6, ALT_VALUE: 76, DLT_VALUE: 70 },
    { id: 7, ALT_VALUE: 9, DLT_VALUE: 15 },
];

const filters = [
    { parameter: "ALT_VALUE", min: 8, max: 100 },
    { parameter: "DLT_VALUE", min: 30, max: 50 },
];

const result = data.filter((el) => {
      return filters.every((f) => {
        if (el[f.parameter] > f.min && el[f.parameter] < f.max) {
            return el;
        }
      });
});

console.log(result)
```